# PHP MySQL Statement not working, no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a website, and I have encountered with an strange MySQL behaviour. I'm trying to use an `MySQL Update Query` with multiple `WHERE` Clauses.

```
$name = $_POST['username'];
$updatequery1 = "UPDATE OTP SET 'Project' = 'ANETSignupUsed' WHERE Name = '$name' AND HashedOTP = '$hashedotp' ";
$sqlconnection->query($updatequery1);
die("DONE");
```

Note that I've already defined `$hashedotp`.

When I try doing the same thing in `MySQL Console` it works pretty well, and I've made sure that the `user` used to define `$sqlconnection` has `Update` rights.

I've tried solutions DESCRIBED

- [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415897/php-mysql-statement-not-working)
- [HERE](https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/227573-resolved-php-mysql-update-not-working)

I've spent hours searching about it, but to no avail.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $updatequery1 = "UPDATE OTP SET Project = 'ANETSignupUsed' WHERE Name = '$name' AND HashedOTP = '$hashedotp' "; try with this query.

Comment: Uh..... it did work! I don't know why but it didn't work a few minutes ago!

Comment: I just remove single quote in set fields :)

Comment: Anyways Thanks a lot @HP371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Remove `single quote` from your query**

```
$updatequery1 = "UPDATE OTP SET Project = 'ANETSignupUsed' WHERE Name = '$name' AND HashedOTP = '$hashedotp' ";
```

Comment: Please give upvote this answer Thank you!!!! @Arag Aggrawal